# Javascript array.length is 0 but array is filled with 40 items

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a big problem in one array of my javascript code :

```
console.dir(particles[idx]);
```

return

```
Array[0]
0: particle
...
39: particle
length: 40
__proto__: Array[0]
 (index):191
```

but

```
console.log("length:"+particles[idx].length);
```

return

```
length:0
```

Any idea why the length value is 0 ?
In the console.dir, the length was 40.

I thought that it was in the array creation but didn't find why.

Here's the code that fill this array (in that case, idx = 1):

```
particles[idx] = [];
(function emitter(cnt) {
    setTimeout(function(){
    particles[idx].push(new particle());
        if (--cnt) emitter(cnt);
        }, 50);
    })(particles_count);
```

Thanks for your help.

[EDIT]

I have this code that return correctly the array length :

```
        (function emitter(i) {
            setTimeout(function () {
            particles.push(new particle());
                if (--i) emitter(i);
            }, 50);
        })(particle_count);
```

The only difference is in the particle array that is not using an index.

Comment: Are you sure you don't log the length before the asynchronous filling of the array ?

Comment: Don't you want the length of `particles`? Based on your info above, `particles` is made up of 40 `particle` elements. You are getting the length of one of the `particle` elements when you do `particles[idx].length`. Try `particles.length`.

Comment: Please show the whole code. There's obviously some timing issue, which isn't apparent when you just show disjoint snippets.

Comment: Well, the last code snippet shows that all elements are being pushed to `particles[idx]` so `particles[idx].length` seems right (unless the value of `idx` changes along the way).

Comment: Since you are `push`ing new `particle`s inside a `setTimeout` you won't see them added immediately.  So for `console.log("length:"+particles[idx].length);` to work, it needs to be called AFTER the last `setTimeout` call.  If you call it earlier, of course the array is still empty/not completely filled.

Comment: As indicate, particle.length return 0 instead of 40.

Comment: There isn't enough information in the question to tell why it wouldn't work.

Comment: You're right ! I have tested by adding console.log(particles[idx].length); in the loop and it works.
But it doesn't explain why it works when there is no [idx].

Comment: It does if you have `idx` in the global scope... Where is `idx` being declared?

Comment: idx and particles are declared in the global scope.

Answer (score 1):

`particles` is an array that has 40 items but `particles[idx].length` returns the length of one of the 40 items length. like:

```
var particles = ['','','',''];
```

`particles.length` is 4 but `particles[0].length` is 0 because `particles[0] = ''`

Comment: Read the comments to the question. The elements are pushed to `particles[idx]`, not `particles`.